# Difference between percentage value all tests and one test method for the class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, developer-console

Why is the difference between the value of the percent coverage of all the tests and one test for the class? I have cleaned the test data. Then compile all classes and then run all the tests organization. And this situation in many classes.

[image]

In Eclipse a more correct value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was because of the difference versions of a class and a test class. In the test class version was lower (29.0) against (30.0) class. After I corrected version of the test class - covering 77% was shown for the case of All tests.

I hope this helps someone.